# 「:target 疑似クラス」のリンクから戻る際、URLに#を付与せず画面遷移したい

Tags: javascript, css

**最終的にやりたいこと**
・[リンク先内容](http://coliss.com/articles/build-websites/operation/css/target-pseudo-class-trick.html)で、「:target 疑似クラス」のリンクから戻る際、URLに#を付与せず(かつページ再読込せず)画面遷移したい

・[先日jsで処理する方法を質問した](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/41980/%E3%83%9A%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B8%E5%86%85%E3%83%AA%E3%83%B3%E3%82%AF%E3%81%A7%E7%A7%BB%E5%8B%95%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E5%BE%8C-%E4%BB%98%E4%B8%8E%E3%81%9B%E3%81%9A%E7%94%BB%E9%9D%A2%E6%9B%B4%E6%96%B0%E3%81%9B%E3%81%9A-%E5%85%83%E3%81%AE%E7%8A%B6%E6%85%8B%E3%81%B8%E9%81%B7%E7%A7%BB%E3%81%95%E3%81%9B%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84)のですが、クリックした際、CSSの「:target 疑似クラス」処理と「js」処理の両方を行う方法はあるでしょうか？

---

**試したこと**
・下記では「return false」しているため、「:target 疑似クラス」内容が反映されません

```
 function move0(){
        history.pushState(null,null,"./test.html");
        return false;
    }
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="move0()"> 1 </a>
```

・下記ではjsの後#で呼び出しているので「:target 疑似クラス」内容は反映されるけれども、URLに#は付与されたままになります

```
 function move0(){
        history.pushState(null,null,"./test.html");
    }
<a href="#" onclick="move0()"> 1 </a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cssのtransition動作イベントを利用したサンプルを書いて見ました。参考になるでしょうか？

```js
$(function(){
            $("#navi").on("oTransitionStart mozTransitionStart webkitTransitionStart transitionstart", function(){
               history.pushState(null, null, "./test2.html");
            });
        });
```

```css
#navi {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        height: 100%;
        width: 80%;
        max-width: 400px;
    }

    #navi:not(:target) {
        right: -100%;
        transition: right 0.5s;
    }

    #navi:target {
        right: 0;
        transition: right 0.5s;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#navi">test</a>

<nav id="navi">
    <a href="#" aria-label="Close Navigation"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>

    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Link One</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: 「Link One」をクリックしてもURLに#は付与されたままになるのですが、「Link One」クリックした時にURLから#を削除する方法はあるでしょうか？

Comment: サンプルは、スタート時に書き換えているので、（私の環境で動作確認済みです。）transitionの終了後にhistory.pushStateを実行すれば良いと思います。"oTransitionEnd mozTransitionEnd webkitTransitionEnd transitionend"　　
ＰＣ、ＳＰ、win,macの各ブラウザーでtransitionのイベント発生タイミングがびみょうに違いますので、同じ要領で調整工夫して下さい。

Comment: "oTransitionEnd mozTransitionEnd webkitTransitionEnd transitionend"に書き換えたら、期待通り動作するようになりました